# find minimum dominating set in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

QUESTION: On clicking a node in a tree, all the adjacent edges that are connected to that node, are turned on. Calculate minimum number of clicks such that all the edges are turned on.

This a interview question which was asked to my friend in some interview, To solve this problem First i thought to do level-order traversal and click nodes at alternate levels, if a leaf is found at current selected level, click on its parent instead of leaf in order to make no of clicks minimum.

But above solution doesn't work for all binary tree structure and giving more no of clicks while even lesser no of clicks can also turn on all the edges.

After searching it on the net, i got to know its a kind of finding minimum Dominating set in a binary tree. 
Please suggest some way to solve this problem efficiently.